# How to remove 3D border of input filed in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, input

I want to add blue shadow highlight for text input when it receives focus:

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #6192D1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #6192D1;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px  #6192D1;       
    outline: 0;
}
```

In Firefox it looks well, but Chome adds some inner 3d looking borders.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hSmA3/)

Chrome adds following styles:

```
border-top-style: inset;
border-top-width: 2px;
border-bottom-style: inset;
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-left-style: inset;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-style: inset;
border-right-width: 2px;
```

If I set something like:

```
border-width: 2px;
border-color: transparent;
border-style: inset;
```

Border has gone in Chrome, but in FF it makes the field resizing on focus.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yKNP/)

Any ideas how to get rid of 3d border not hurting the appearence in FF?

Comment: Did you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your html page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all you are adding a `2px` `border` on `:focus`, so hence, the field moves as `border` takes space outside the element and not inside, to get rid of the Chromes grey border, you need to use `-webkit-appearance: none;` and also use `-moz-appearance: none;` which will get rid of the grey border in chrome, and nice looking `input` field in firefox...

```
input {
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance: none; 
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yKNP/1/)

Now, to standardize more, add `border: 2px solid #eee;` on the `input` tag

```
input {
    padding: 4px;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance: none; 
    border: 2px solid #eee; /* Here */
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yKNP/3/)

---

> Note: You are using general element selectors, so all the `input`
>   fields will be affected, consider using a `class` or an `id` instead.